# Django Testing view template context

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm trying to test the

`return render(request, 'template.html', context)`

and seem to be falling short. Is it not worth while testing this? Or if it is worth while testing this, how do I accomplish that?

view.py

```
def create_employee_profile(request):
    name_form = EmployeeNameForm()
    context = {'name_form':name_form}
    return render(request,
                'template_create_employee_profile.html',
                context
                )
```

I know the `if: else:` statements are missing. I didn't think they were relevant to the test.

test.py

```
# TEST:  context({'name_form':name_form})
def test_CreateEmployeeProfileView_context(self):
    name_form = EmployeeNameForm()
    response = self.client.get(reverse(
                            'create_employee_profile'))
    self.assertEquals(response.context['name_form'], name_form)
```

This got me the closest to success. Here's my error:

```
AssertionError: <Empl[27 chars]alid=False,
                fields=(employee_choices;first_nam[20 chars]ame)> != 
                <Empl[27 chars]alid=Unknown,
                fields=(employee_choices;first_n[22 chars]ame)>
```

What about the detail view?

```
# TEST:  context({'name':name})
def test_CustomerEmployeeProfileView_context(self):
    name = CustomerEmployeeName.objects.get(pk=1)
    response = self.client.get(
        reverse('service:customer_employee_profile_detail', kwargs={'pk': 1}))

    self.assertIsInstance(response.context['name'], name)
```

Got this error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are comparing two different instances of the `EmployeeNameForm`, which is why the assertion fails.

If you just want to test that the context variable is indeed a `EmployeeNameForm` then you can test it with [assertIsInstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance):

```
def test_CreateEmployeeProfileView_context(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('create_employee_profile'))
    self.assertIsInstance(response.context['name_form'], EmployeeNameForm)
```

Comment: What about a detail view `name = get_object_or_404(CustomerEmployeeName, pk=pk)
    context = {'name': name}` @solarissmoke

Comment: There you can compare the objects directly as you're comparing identical model instances.

Comment: Check my above test for the detail view. What did I miss? @solarissmoke

Comment: You don't need to do `assertIsInstance` there. Simply check that `name` equals `response.context['name']`.